# How to loop Grass command in Python and put variable in output file

Tags: python, grass-gis, loop

I want to reclassify the same raster several times and then save the file with the value loop variable at the end ...
I cannot get it working.

```
    import sys
    import os
    import atexit

    import grass.script as grass

    def cleanup():
        pass

    def main():
        for i in range (2,4):
        out = "reclasstest" + str(i)
        rulesvar = "C:\Grass_data\datareclassfile") + str(i) 
        grass.run_command("r.reclass",
                          overwrite = True,
                          input = "glg@PERMANENT",
                          output = out,
                          rules = rulesvar)

        return 0

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        options, flags = grass.parser()
        atexit.register(cleanup)
        sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an indentation problem, plus had an extra ")" and was missing an "r" on a file path - try ...

```
import sys
import os
import atexit

import grass.script as grass

def cleanup():
    pass

def main():
    for i in range (2,4):
        out = "reclasstest" + str(i)
        rulesvar = r"C:\Grass_data\datareclassfile" + str(i) 
        grass.run_command("r.reclass",
                          overwrite = True,
                          input = "glg@PERMANENT",
                          output = out,
                          rules = rulesvar)

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options, flags = grass.parser()
    atexit.register(cleanup)
    sys.exit(main())
```

If this does not work be sure to post any error message you receive.